# Copying file obj\Debug\build.force to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\build.force failed. Could not find file 'obj\Debug\build.force'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error while am publishing the project to local system

> Copying file obj\Debug\build.force to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\build.force failed. Could not
>   find file 'obj\Debug\build.force'

I am not able to find the proper solution.

Tried Restarting VS
Deleted Bin Folder and rebuild the project again

Answer (score 5):

you just delete that whole folder(obj\Debug) from the solution(don't delete it from the directory) and try to publish it will definitely work.

Comment: Do you mean to exclude the obj\Debug folder from Solution ?

Comment: Not to exclude . just delete.

Comment: I simply excluded the entire obj folder, and the error went away.